# Surjective function from a set of funtions to itself

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

Let a function be defined by $f \longmapsto f'$ acting from the set of all polynomials to itself.

I am asked if this is surjective. I would like to think it isn't, but I'm in doubt how I should interpret this function. The order of the polynomial can be infinite, so the order of the derivative can also be as high as possible. Does this imply that it is surjective?

My original thought was to define the order of the polynomial to be n, which would imply that the function is not surjective, since it doesnt map into all polynomials.

Thanks.

Comment: you can always integrate any polynomial

Comment: There are polynomials with arbitrary large order, but that's not the same as the existence of polynomials of infinite order. One standard technique for showing surjectivity of a map is finding for each element in the codomain an element in the domain which maps to it. Can you do that for an arbitrary polynomial here? NB, this roughly amounts to "undoing" a differentiation.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$p(x)= \sum_{k=0}^n a_nx^n$$
be any polynomial and consider 
$$q(x) =\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_n}{n+1}x^{n+1},$$
then clearly $q'(x)=p(x)$.

Comment: Right, but then you don't get any polynomials in the codomain of order n+1...?

Comment: If you denote by $P_n$ the set of all polynomials of degree at most $n$ then $f: P_n \to P_n$ is not surjective, however $f: \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}P_n \to \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}P_n$ is surjective.